# Graphite - 1sec data retention for long time makes hundreds GB of disk space

Tags: database, storage, graphite

I have to configure graphite to hold data with 1sec resolution for important data.I'm not going to have a lot of this ,high resolution is important for me.

Yesterday I created about ~400 metrics each with 12 values and the DB size increased to 300 GB

```
pattern = .*
retentions = 1s:1800d
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Graphite's backing database, Whisper, uses flat files as a storage mechanism. It calculates how much space will be needed to store a continuous stream of data at your resolution for the entire retention period *as soon as the metric is created*. This is because *all time-slots within an archive take up space whether or not a value is stored*.If you don't add any more metrics, then you needn't worry about your storage footprint expanding further.

See http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whisper.html